# Detecting inner RecyclerView reaches top or bottom

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have an activity with a RecyclerView inside another RecyclerView.

When the inner RV is scrolled I'm disabling the outer using:

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
            int action = e.getAction();
            switch (action) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    rv.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

I want to enable the outer RV when the inner RV has no scroll left, so if the user reaches the top of it, I won't disable the outer RV and it will scroll in that direction, and also the same behaviour for the bottom.

I've tried the following code, but seems that ACTION_UP and ACTION_DOWN can't be used to achieve what I want.

```
addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
            if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                if (innerRV.canScrollVertically(-1)) {
                    rv.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                }
            } else if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                if (innerRV.canScrollVertically(1)) {
                    rv.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Is there another way I can achieve the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to `recyclerView.setOnScrollListener()` and inside `onScrolled()` method you can check first and last visible item via `layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()` and `layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition()`